# T test in a cross tabulated table

Tags: r

I have a table like so:

```
 1   2   3   4   5
 10  22  15  14  3
 15  44  22  26  9
 ...more rows
```

I want to run a t test on a single row to find out if it's plausible that its mean is less than 3. Using t.test(table[x, ]) doesn't work, because it assumes I'm interested in the mean of the values in the row, which I'm not: the values just indicate the number of responses to each value on a scale of 1-5.

How do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following approach:

1. Ungroup you data
2. Apply the t.test to each row

`apply(data, 1, function(data) {t.test( rep(1:5, times = data), alternative = "less", mu = 3)})`

Which will return a t-test for each row, e.g.:

```
[[1]]

One Sample t-test

data:  rep(1:5, times = data)
t = -2.4337, df = 63, p-value = 0.008896
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 3
95 percent confidence interval:
  -Inf 2.892043
sample estimates:
  mean of x 
2.65625 


[[2]]

One Sample t-test

data:  rep(1:5, times = data)
t = -2.3745, df = 115, p-value = 0.009613
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 3
95 percent confidence interval:
  -Inf 2.921981
sample estimates:
  mean of x 
2.741379
```

If you want just the p-values then add `$p.value`:

```
apply(data, 1, function(data) {t.test( rep(1:5, times = data), alternative = "less", mu = 3)$p.value})

[1] 0.008895887 0.009613075
```